# How to fix VS Code error with Remote-SSH: "the terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed.)."?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal, vscode-remote

I've installed and used the [Remote-SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension in VS Code to access a Linux staging environment and work remotely.

The setup and connection works for one user, however is not allowing me to connect as a different user (on the same server).

Immediately after connecting, an error pops up saying `the terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed.).` and the terminal would fail to open. If I attempt to manually open the terminal, it will fail with the same error.

Here is an example of how my Remote-SSH config file looks:

```
Host configfile1
  HostName host.website.com
  User username1
  IdentifyFile "[key file path]"

Host configfile2
  HostName host.website.com
  User username2
  IdentifyFile "[key file path]"
```

I could connect just fine and open remote terminal with `configfile1`, however would run into the aforementioned error when attempting to connect with `configfile2`.

I have tried various solutions mentioned in this GitHub issues thread, but to no avail: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4233

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the underlying causes for this, but this error pops up when using **jailed** shell settings.

Try changing the user's SSH shell settings to **normal** shell, and you may be able to connect without an issue.

This may not be ideal for all scenarios or security considerations, however, but it will allow Remote-SSH to connect and spawn the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

go to user setting UI and find this:

Remote.SSH: Show Login Terminal

tick: Always reveal the SSH login terminal

this will remove that warning,

the terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed.

Comment: In my case, the warning was an *exception* that prevented the terminal from actually connecting. The SSH user I was connecting with was a "jailed shell" user. However when the same user was changed on the destination server to a "normal shell" user, I was able to SSH in normally. In all attempts, the SSH key remained the same. The issue appeared to be due to the connecting user's permissions on the destination server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The issue has to do with your internet connection. I don't really know the cause but switching to a better connection will generally solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any data to back up this claim? The answer I left after I found the solution worked 100% of the time.